# Skype Crash Mac OS High Sierra 10.13.1 - How to fix this?

Tags: macos, crash, skype

To start by saying that I fixed the 'first crash' by disabling the notification within skype it was crashing as soon as someone send a message while Skype was in the background. 
I thought I'll just reinstall and apply the common diagnoses and fix. 
Uninstall deleting  .com.skype.skype.plist and other skype files.

Also tried first aid (disk utility) and installing system updates e.g.  softwareupdate (all)

Now the issue (crash) happens when anyone calls on the Skype.

My idea is that EXC_CRASH  is calling abort() I still have no idea what's actually going on.

Feel free to post **ANY** possible solutions and I'll happily give the reward if it works.

```
    Process:               Skype [17598]
Path:                  /Volumes/*/Skype.app/Contents/MacOS/Skype
Identifier:            com.skype.skype
Version:               8.12 (8.12.0.2)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Skype [17598]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2017-12-11 09:59:50.809 +0000
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.13.1 (17B48)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        62A7D3F8-8555-776B-13BE-A27DC33735AA

Sleep/Wake UUID:       A04E67E4-4641-402C-B4C4-32DCD69445CF

Time Awake Since Boot: 370000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       6400 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  CrBrowserMain  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
abort() called
*** error for object 0x10fa6b01b: Non-aligned pointer being freed


Thread 0 Crashed:: CrBrowserMain  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff7ec01fce __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7ed3f150 pthread_kill + 333
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff7eb5e30a abort + 127
3   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x00007fff7ec66b28 szone_error + 596
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff573b5e9b __CFStringCreateImmutableFunnel3 + 2603
5   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff5742089a CFStringCreateWithCStringNoCopy + 74
6   com.ecamm.CallRecorder          0x000000010fa5600a checkVersion3 + 45
7   com.ecamm.CallRecorder          0x000000010fa44ca9 0x10fa40000 + 19625
8   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff59543985 __NSThreadPerformPerform + 334
9   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff5744fad1 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
10  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff5750754c __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 108
11  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff57432b1c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 300
12  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff57431f3d __CFRunLoopRun + 1293
13  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff57431797 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 487
14  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff56746866 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 286
15  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff567465d6 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 613
16  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff56746354 _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 64
17  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff54a43a23 _DPSNextEvent + 2085
18  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff551d8e6c -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 3044
19  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff54a38831 -[NSApplication run] + 764
20  com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001093fc7de 0x1091a8000 + 2443230
21  com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001093fbdcc 0x1091a8000 + 2440652
22  com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001093f80ae 0x1091a8000 + 2425006
23  com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001094111e3 0x1091a8000 + 2527715
24  com.github.electron.framework   0x000000010967b80f 0x1091a8000 + 5060623
25  com.github.electron.framework   0x000000010967b630 0x1091a8000 + 5060144
26  com.github.electron.framework   0x000000010967ded2 0x1091a8000 + 5070546
27  com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001096774ec 0x1091a8000 + 5043436
28  com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001095cdc6b 0x1091a8000 + 4349035
29  com.github.electron.framework   0x000000010b0927b8 0x1091a8000 + 32417720
30  com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001095ccec4 0x1091a8000 + 4345540
31  com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001091aa94a AtomMain + 74
32  com.skype.skype                 0x000000010589ff26 main + 38
33  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff7eab2145 start + 1

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff7ebf8e76 mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff7ebf8390 mach_msg + 60
2   com.github.electron.framework   0x0000000109330fd0 0x1091a8000 + 1609680
3   com.github.electron.framework   0x0000000109330f2b crashpad::MachMessageWithDeadline(mach_msg_header_t*, int, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned long long, unsigned int, bool) + 171
4   com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001093317a7 0x1091a8000 + 1611687
5   com.github.electron.framework   0x0000000109331565 crashpad::MachMessageServer::Run(crashpad::MachMessageServer::Interface*, unsigned int, int, crashpad::MachMessageServer::Persistent, crashpad::MachMessageServer::ReceiveLarge, unsigned int) + 405
6   com.github.electron.framework   0x000000010932ac22 0x1091a8000 + 1584162
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7ed3c6c1 _pthread_body + 340
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7ed3c56d _pthread_start + 377
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7ed3bc5d thread_start + 13

Thread 2:: NetworkConfigWatcher
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff7ebf8e76 mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff7ebf8390 mach_msg + 60
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff57432dd5 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 341
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff57432127 __CFRunLoopRun + 1783
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff57431797 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 487
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff594fc3f6 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 277
6   com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001093fc60e 0x1091a8000 + 2442766
7   com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001093fbdcc 0x1091a8000 + 2440652
8   com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001093f80ae 0x1091a8000 + 2425006
9   com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001094111e3 0x1091a8000 + 2527715
10  com.github.electron.framework   0x0000000109433089 0x1091a8000 + 2666633
11  com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001094060b7 0x1091a8000 + 2482359
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7ed3c6c1 _pthread_body + 340
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7ed3c56d _pthread_start + 377
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7ed3bc5d thread_start + 13

Thread 3:: DnsConfigService
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff7ec0303a kevent + 10
1   com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001094638d9 0x1091a8000 + 2865369
2   com.github.electron.framework   0x0000000109462a6d 0x1091a8000 + 2861677
3   com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001093fb3df 0x1091a8000 + 2438111
4   com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001093f80ae 0x1091a8000 + 2425006
5   com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001094111e3 0x1091a8000 + 2527715
6   com.github.electron.framework   0x0000000109433089 0x1091a8000 + 2666633
7   com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001094060b7 0x1091a8000 + 2482359
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7ed3c6c1 _pthread_body + 340
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7ed3c56d _pthread_start + 377
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7ed3bc5d thread_start + 13

Thread 4:: CrShutdownDetector
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff7ec03592 read + 10
1   com.github.electron.framework   0x000000010924409f 0x1091a8000 + 639135
2   com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001094060b7 0x1091a8000 + 2482359
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7ed3c6c1 _pthread_body + 340
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7ed3c56d _pthread_start + 377
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7ed3bc5d thread_start + 13

Thread 5:: TaskSchedulerServiceThread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff7ec0303a kevent + 10
1   com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001094638d9 0x1091a8000 + 2865369
2   com.github.electron.framework   0x0000000109462a6d 0x1091a8000 + 2861677
3   com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001093fb3df 0x1091a8000 + 2438111
4   com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001093f80ae 0x1091a8000 + 2425006
5   com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001094111e3 0x1091a8000 + 2527715
6   com.github.electron.framework   0x0000000109433089 0x1091a8000 + 2666633
7   com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001094060b7 0x1091a8000 + 2482359
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7ed3c6c1 _pthread_body + 340
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7ed3c56d _pthread_start + 377
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7ed3bc5d thread_start + 13

Thread 6:: TaskSchedulerBackgroundWorker0
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff7ec01e7e __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7ed3d69b _pthread_cond_wait + 789
2   com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001093afebb 0x1091a8000 + 2129595
3   com.github.electron.framework   0x000000010945bbf0 0x1091a8000 + 2833392
4   com.github.electron.framework   0x000000010945bd21 0x1091a8000 + 2833697
5   com.github.electron.framework   0x0000000109413468 0x1091a8000 + 2536552
6   com.github.electron.framework   0x0000000109413b2d 0x1091a8000 + 2538285
7   com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001094060b7 0x1091a8000 + 2482359
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7ed3c6c1 _pthread_body + 340
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7ed3c56d _pthread_start + 377
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7ed3bc5d thread_start + 13

Thread 7:: TaskSchedulerBackgroundBlockingWorker0
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff7ec01e7e __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7ed3d69b _pthread_cond_wait + 789
2   com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001093afebb 0x1091a8000 + 2129595
3   com.github.electron.framework   0x000000010945bbf0 0x1091a8000 + 2833392
4   com.github.electron.framework   0x000000010945bd21 0x1091a8000 + 2833697
5   com.github.electron.framework   0x0000000109413468 0x1091a8000 + 2536552
6   com.github.electron.framework   0x0000000109413b2d 0x1091a8000 + 2538285
7   com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001094060b7 0x1091a8000 + 2482359
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7ed3c6c1 _pthread_body + 340
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7ed3c56d _pthread_start + 377
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7ed3bc5d thread_start + 13

Thread 8:: TaskSchedulerForegroundWorker0
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff7ec01e7e __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7ed3d69b _pthread_cond_wait + 789
2   com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001093afebb 0x1091a8000 + 2129595
3   com.github.electron.framework   0x000000010945bbf0 0x1091a8000 + 2833392
4   com.github.electron.framework   0x000000010945bd21 0x1091a8000 + 2833697
5   com.github.electron.framework   0x0000000109413468 0x1091a8000 + 2536552
6   com.github.electron.framework   0x0000000109413b2d 0x1091a8000 + 2538285
7   com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001094060b7 0x1091a8000 + 2482359
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7ed3c6c1 _pthread_body + 340
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7ed3c56d _pthread_start + 377
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7ed3bc5d thread_start + 13

Thread 9:: TaskSchedulerForegroundBlockingWorker0
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff7ec01e7e __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7ed3d69b _pthread_cond_wait + 789
2   com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001093afebb 0x1091a8000 + 2129595
3   com.github.electron.framework   0x000000010945bbf0 0x1091a8000 + 2833392
4   com.github.electron.framework   0x000000010945bd21 0x1091a8000 + 2833697
5   com.github.electron.framework   0x0000000109413468 0x1091a8000 + 2536552
6   com.github.electron.framework   0x0000000109413b2d 0x1091a8000 + 2538285
7   com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001094060b7 0x1091a8000 + 2482359
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7ed3c6c1 _pthread_body + 340
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7ed3c56d _pthread_start + 377
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7ed3bc5d thread_start + 13

Thread 10:: Chrome_DBThread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff7ebf8e76 mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff7ebf8390 mach_msg + 60
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff57432dd5 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 341
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff57432127 __CFRunLoopRun + 1783
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff57431797 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 487
5   com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001093fc32f 0x1091a8000 + 2442031
6   com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001093fbdcc 0x1091a8000 + 2440652
7   com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001093f80ae 0x1091a8000 + 2425006
8   com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001094111e3 0x1091a8000 + 2527715
9   com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001096888e8 0x1091a8000 + 5114088
10  com.github.electron.framework   0x0000000109688caf 0x1091a8000 + 5115055
11  com.github.electron.framework   0x0000000109433089 0x1091a8000 + 2666633
12  com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001094060b7 0x1091a8000 + 2482359
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7ed3c6c1 _pthread_body + 340
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7ed3c56d _pthread_start + 377
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7ed3bc5d thread_start + 13

Thread 11:: Chrome_FileThread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff7ec0303a kevent + 10
1   com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001094638d9 0x1091a8000 + 2865369
2   com.github.electron.framework   0x0000000109462a6d 0x1091a8000 + 2861677
3   com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001093fb3df 0x1091a8000 + 2438111
4   com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001093f80ae 0x1091a8000 + 2425006
5   com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001094111e3 0x1091a8000 + 2527715
6   com.github.electron.framework   0x0000000109688968 0x1091a8000 + 5114216
7   com.github.electron.framework   0x0000000109688cbf 0x1091a8000 + 5115071
8   com.github.electron.framework   0x0000000109433089 0x1091a8000 + 2666633
9   com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001094060b7 0x1091a8000 + 2482359
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7ed3c6c1 _pthread_body + 340
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7ed3c56d _pthread_start + 377
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7ed3bc5d thread_start + 13

Thread 12:: Chrome_FileUserBlockingThread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff7ebf8e76 mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff7ebf8390 mach_msg + 60
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff57432dd5 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 341
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff57432127 __CFRunLoopRun + 1783
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff57431797 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 487
5   com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001093fc32f 0x1091a8000 + 2442031
6   com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001093fbdcc 0x1091a8000 + 2440652
7   com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001093f80ae 0x1091a8000 + 2425006
8   com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001094111e3 0x1091a8000 + 2527715
9   com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001096889e8 0x1091a8000 + 5114344
10  com.github.electron.framework   0x0000000109688ccf 0x1091a8000 + 5115087
11  com.github.electron.framework   0x0000000109433089 0x1091a8000 + 2666633
12  com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001094060b7 0x1091a8000 + 2482359
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7ed3c6c1 _pthread_body + 340
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7ed3c56d _pthread_start + 377
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7ed3bc5d thread_start + 13

Thread 13:: Chrome_ProcessLauncherThread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff7ebf8e76 mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff7ebf8390 mach_msg + 60
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff57432dd5 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 341
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff57432127 __CFRunLoopRun + 1783
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff57431797 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 487
5   com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001093fc32f 0x1091a8000 + 2442031
6   com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001093fbdcc 0x1091a8000 + 2440652
7   com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001093f80ae 0x1091a8000 + 2425006
8   com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001094111e3 0x1091a8000 + 2527715
9   com.github.electron.framework   0x0000000109688a68 0x1091a8000 + 5114472
10  com.github.electron.framework   0x0000000109688cdc 0x1091a8000 + 5115100
11  com.github.electron.framework   0x0000000109433089 0x1091a8000 + 2666633
12  com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001094060b7 0x1091a8000 + 2482359
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7ed3c6c1 _pthread_body + 340
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7ed3c56d _pthread_start + 377
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7ed3bc5d thread_start + 13

Thread 14:: Chrome_CacheThread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff7ebf8e76 mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff7ebf8390 mach_msg + 60
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff57432dd5 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 341
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff57432127 __CFRunLoopRun + 1783
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff57431797 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 487
5   com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001093fc32f 0x1091a8000 + 2442031
6   com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001093fbdcc 0x1091a8000 + 2440652
7   com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001093f80ae 0x1091a8000 + 2425006
8   com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001094111e3 0x1091a8000 + 2527715
9   com.github.electron.framework   0x0000000109688ae8 0x1091a8000 + 5114600
10  com.github.electron.framework   0x0000000109688ce9 0x1091a8000 + 5115113
11  com.github.electron.framework   0x0000000109433089 0x1091a8000 + 2666633
12  com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001094060b7 0x1091a8000 + 2482359
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7ed3c6c1 _pthread_body + 340
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7ed3c56d _pthread_start + 377
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7ed3bc5d thread_start + 13

Thread 15:: Chrome_IOThread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff7ec0303a kevent + 10
1   com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001094638d9 0x1091a8000 + 2865369
2   com.github.electron.framework   0x0000000109462a6d 0x1091a8000 + 2861677
3   com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001093fb3c6 0x1091a8000 + 2438086
4   com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001093f80ae 0x1091a8000 + 2425006
5   com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001094111e3 0x1091a8000 + 2527715
6   com.github.electron.framework   0x0000000109688b68 0x1091a8000 + 5114728
7   com.github.electron.framework   0x0000000109688cf6 0x1091a8000 + 5115126
8   com.github.electron.framework   0x0000000109433089 0x1091a8000 + 2666633
9   com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001094060b7 0x1091a8000 + 2482359
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7ed3c6c1 _pthread_body + 340
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7ed3c56d _pthread_start + 377
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7ed3bc5d thread_start + 13

Thread 16:: IndexedDB
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff7ebf8e76 mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff7ebf8390 mach_msg + 60
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff57432dd5 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 341
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff57432127 __CFRunLoopRun + 1783
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff57431797 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 487
5   com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001093fc32f 0x1091a8000 + 2442031
6   com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001093fbdcc 0x1091a8000 + 2440652
7   com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001093f80ae 0x1091a8000 + 2425006
8   com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001094111e3 0x1091a8000 + 2527715
9   com.github.electron.framework   0x0000000109433089 0x1091a8000 + 2666633
10  com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001094060b7 0x1091a8000 + 2482359
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7ed3c6c1 _pthread_body + 340
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7ed3c56d _pthread_start + 377
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7ed3bc5d thread_start + 13

Thread 17:: CompositorTileWorker1/50691
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff7ec01e7e __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7ed3d662 _pthread_cond_wait + 732
2   com.github.electron.framework   0x000000010955d4f8 0x1091a8000 + 3888376
3   com.github.electron.framework   0x000000010941dacc 0x1091a8000 + 2579148
4   com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001094060b7 0x1091a8000 + 2482359
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7ed3c6c1 _pthread_body + 340
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7ed3c56d _pthread_start + 377
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7ed3bc5d thread_start + 13

Thread 18:: AudioThread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff7ebf8e76 mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff7ebf8390 mach_msg + 60
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff57432dd5 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 341
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff57432127 __CFRunLoopRun + 1783
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff57431797 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 487
5   com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001093fc32f 0x1091a8000 + 2442031
6   com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001093fbdcc 0x1091a8000 + 2440652
7   com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001093f80ae 0x1091a8000 + 2425006
8   com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001094111e3 0x1091a8000 + 2527715
9   com.github.electron.framework   0x0000000109433089 0x1091a8000 + 2666633
10  com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001094060b7 0x1091a8000 + 2482359
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7ed3c6c1 _pthread_body + 340
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7ed3c56d _pthread_start + 377
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7ed3bc5d thread_start + 13

Thread 19:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff7ec02142 __select + 10
1   com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001092c0922 atom::NodeBindingsMac::PollEvents() + 210
2   com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001092bffbf atom::NodeBindings::EmbedThreadRunner(void*) + 63
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7ed3c6c1 _pthread_body + 340
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7ed3c56d _pthread_start + 377
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7ed3bc5d thread_start + 13

Thread 20:: BrowserBlockingWorker1/63491
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff7ec01e7e __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7ed3d69b _pthread_cond_wait + 789
2   com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001093afebb 0x1091a8000 + 2129595
3   com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001094194b6 0x1091a8000 + 2561206
4   com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001094183b6 0x1091a8000 + 2556854
5   com.github.electron.framework   0x000000010941dacc 0x1091a8000 + 2579148
6   com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001094060b7 0x1091a8000 + 2482359
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7ed3c6c1 _pthread_body + 340
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7ed3c56d _pthread_start + 377
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7ed3bc5d thread_start + 13

Thread 21:: NetworkConfigWatcher
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff7ebf8e76 mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff7ebf8390 mach_msg + 60
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff57432dd5 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 341
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff57432127 __CFRunLoopRun + 1783
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff57431797 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 487
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff594fc3f6 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 277
6   com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001093fc60e 0x1091a8000 + 2442766
7   com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001093fbdcc 0x1091a8000 + 2440652
8   com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001093f80ae 0x1091a8000 + 2425006
9   com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001094111e3 0x1091a8000 + 2527715
10  com.github.electron.framework   0x0000000109433089 0x1091a8000 + 2666633
11  com.github.electron.framework   0x00000001094060b7 0x1091a8000 + 2482359
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7ed3c6c1 _pthread_body + 340
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7ed3c56d _pthread_start + 377
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7ed3bc5d thread_start + 13

Thread 22:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff7ec01e7e __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7ed3d662 _pthread_cond_wait + 732
2   libnode.dylib                   0x0000000105b68059 uv_cond_wait + 9
3   libnode.dylib                   0x0000000105b5c023 0x1059e6000 + 1531939
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7ed3c6c1 _pthread_body + 340
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7ed3c56d _pthread_start + 377
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7ed3bc5d thread_start + 13

Thread 23:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff7ec01e7e __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7ed3d662 _pthread_cond_wait + 732
2   libnode.dylib                   0x0000000105b68059 uv_cond_wait + 9
3   libnode.dylib                   0x0000000105b5c023 0x1059e6000 + 1531939
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7ed3c6c1 _pthread_body + 340
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7ed3c56d _pthread_start + 377
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7ed3bc5d thread_start + 13

Thread 24:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff7ec01e7e __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7ed3d662 _pthread_cond_wait + 732
2   libnode.dylib                   0x0000000105b68059 uv_cond_wait + 9
3   libnode.dylib                   0x0000000105b5c023 0x1059e6000 + 1531939
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7ed3c6c1 _pthread_body + 340
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7ed3c56d _pthread_start + 377
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7ed3bc5d thread_start + 13

Thread 25:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff7ec01e7e __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7ed3d662 _pthread_cond_wait + 732
2   libnode.dylib                   0x0000000105b68059 uv_cond_wait + 9
3   libnode.dylib                   0x0000000105b5c023 0x1059e6000 + 1531939
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7ed3c6c1 _pthread_body + 340
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7ed3c56d _pthread_start + 377
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7ed3bc5d thread_start + 13

Thread 26:: com.apple.NSEventThread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff7ebf8e76 mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff7ebf8390 mach_msg + 60
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff57432dd5 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 341
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff57432127 __CFRunLoopRun + 1783
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff57431797 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 487
5   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff54b812d1 _NSEventThread + 184
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7ed3c6c1 _pthread_body + 340
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7ed3c56d _pthread_start + 377
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7ed3bc5d thread_start + 13
```

Comment: Are you using the newer version of Skype (with the dark interface)?

Comment: Yes, thank you for your quick response. It is also the lastest version.

Comment: I am curious why Skype is being run from an external or network mounted volume and not from the Applications directory..

Comment: It does not run from a network mounted volume.

Comment: Are you using http://www.ecamm.com/mac/callrecorder/ with Skype? Crash report shows problem with `com.ecamm.CallRecorder` library.

Comment: You can try to update ecamm to the newest version (2.7.2) Source: https://www.ecamm.com/support/article/1008/skype-quits-on-launch/

Comment: I'll try that Mateusz I'll let you know if that works so that you can reply and take the bounty!

Comment: Still crashes with removing it, nothing helped so far.

Comment: @ElvirMuslic are the crash reports the same after CallRecorder removal?

Comment: @MateuszSzlosek Great answer! Post it and I'll mark it as the correct one! Sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is caused by the [Ecamm Call Recorder](http://www.ecamm.com/mac/callrecorder/). This can be seen in the crash report as `com.ecamm.CallRecorder` library.

To solve it you should update the Ecamm app as proposed in this thread on their [website](https://www.ecamm.com/support/article/1008/skype-quits-on-launch/) or remove it completly.

Comment: I'm sorry the bounty offer is gone, thank you for the response!